# In Phpmyadmin edit values inserted in table is not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

If you see in the picture , i am not getting any option to edit inserted values in table. I wanted to edit here for ex , 'test_input' coloumn for the only entry. Why is this happening , i am on Localhost and newly installed xampp.

[image: screenshot of phpmyadmin]

Comment: **PhpMyAdmin** sometimes complains about no `UNIQUE` key in table. Show us your schema, please :)

Comment: Hey @PaulTomkiel , its fixed now , i added a serial nos coloumn and set it primary along with auto-increment and it works now . Thanks still :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you don't have a `PRIMARY` key in your table.

Add `id` field and set it to be the `PRIMARY` key of your table (or choose one of the existing field, such as `problem_id`, but it must be `UNIQUE`).

This is exactly the notice displayed on top of your attached phpMyAdmin screenshot warns you about:

> Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.